# Batch file to search for the existance of .odex file in android system/app

Tags: android, search, if-statement, batch-file, find

I am working on a large batch file and have a small section that I need help with. I want to do the following. For every *.apk in \mod folder search the phone /system/app for the the .odex version of the filename in mod. Print whether it exists or not. Below is the code I have so far. If I remove the for statement and type in the apkname instead of the variable it will work. But once I add the for line it always returns an errorlevel greater than 1 so it always says it exists whether it does or not. Your help is greatly appreciated.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /r "%~dp0"\mod %%f in (*.apk) DO (
set apkname=%%~nf
set mobile_path=/system/app
adb shell ls %mobile_path% | find /c "!apkanme!.odex" >NUL
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
    echo the file exists
) else (
    echo the file does not exist
)
)
```

Comment: Use find.exe without the /c switch but add /i if you want the search to be case insensitive.  I think that your main issue is that %errorlevel% should be !errorlevel!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some errors and some typos here, try this:

```
@echo off &SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /r "%~dp0\mod" %%f in (*.apk) DO (
    set "apkname=%%~nf"
    set "mobile_path=\system\app"
    adb shell ls !mobile_path! | find /i "!apkname!.odex" >NUL
    if !ERRORLEVEL! equ 0 (echo the file exists) else echo the file does not exist
)
```

Btw. I know batch, not `adb`.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I changed mobile_path and ERRORLEVEL from % to ! and it worked. I left everything else the same. !apkanme!.odex was just a test to make it show as not being there.

Answer (score 0):

The final result of the working batch section is below. @echo off was already set in another section of the batch file.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /r "%~dp0"\mod %%f in (*.apk) DO (
    set apkname=%%~nf
    set mobile_path=/system/app
    adb shell ls !mobile_path! | find /c "!apkname!.odex" >NUL
    if !ERRORLEVEL! == 0 (
        echo the file exists
    ) else (
        echo the file does not exist
    )
)
```